# Multiple power supply for arduino controlled dc motor

Tags: arduino-uno, power, motor, h-bridge

I’m working on a project where I want to control a motorized fader with an arduino.  I have a dual H-Bridge board to control the motor, but the thing is that it is a 10V motor.  I’m thinking of using a secondary power supply on the H-Bridge to power the motor with a proper voltage.
So here is where my lack of electrical knowledge comes into play.  My H-Bridge has the following connections: a set of +/- poles to provide the power to the motors, 4 motor control pins (2 per motor to control their direction) and 4 motor power pins (2 per motor).

If I was using the Arduino as the power source for the DC motor, I would connect the +5v rail to the + terminal ot the H-Bridge and the Gnd rail to the - terminal, which would, in turn act as the ground return for the control pins.

If I am to use an external power supply, how do I wire it properly so I don’t blowup the arduino or the h-bridge?  I’m guessing that my secondary power supply will be connected to the +/- poles of the H-Bridge and the the - pole will also get connected to the Gnd rail of the arduino?

Is that correct?

Comment: Possibly, but it's ultimately not possible to say without the documentation of this motor shield.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It’s not an arduino shield, it’s a generic H-Bridge board.  I’ll try to find more documentation, but it’s relatively hard to find the paperwork for stuff bought on ebay ;)

Comment: To an extent, then it's not really an Arduino question.  The Arduino should have a common ground with the compatible-signal-voltage "digital" side of a motor driver it commands.  What happens on the power side is a question about the details of the motor driver circuit, not an Arduino question.  Without documentation you may need to do some visual/continuity reverse engineering from the data sheet of the driver IC or raw circuit topology if it is made of discrete FETs.

Comment: The board is based on a L298N chip...  ill dig further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet on the L298 IC the connections you described should be right. First I would recommend to connect 10v to the + and - rails and measure the voltage on the logical inputs if it is 0 or lower than 3v than that should be ok to connect an arduino. Also now you can connect an additional 5v power supply with an the -5v connected to the - rail on the board and try to connect the +5v volts to the inputs and measure the voltages on the output (or connect an motor) if everything is ok you can try to connect your Arduino.